# Annotating sentence with BILOU tags for spaCy

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition

How should I annotate (define entities in) the following sentence with BILOU tags?
Especially, how should I handle special characters/punctuation which are attached to words without any space since BILOU doens't provide the character position? e.g `(Principal`,  `(Co-investigator)`, `Dr.` etc.

> Dr. med. XYZ DEF (Principal Investigator)  XYZ ABC (Co-investigator), Dr. med. XYZ RST (Independent Rater)

Should I consider `(Principal` as single entity?

Answer (score 1):

For BILOU tagging you need to have pre-tokenized text. Whether `(Principal` is one token or two depends on your tokenizer, but it would usually be split.

Here's an example of BILOU using spaCy with the default english model and some basic tags:

```
Dr.    O
med    O
.    O
XYZ    B-PERSON
DEF    L-PERSON
(    O
Principal    B-ROLE
Investigator    L-ROLE
)    O
XYZ    B-PERSON
ABC    L-PERSON
(    O
Co    B-ROLE
-    I-ROLE
investigator    L-ROLE
)    O
,    O
Dr.    O
med    O
.    O
XYZ    B-PERSON
RST    L-PERSON
(    O
Independent    B-ROLE
Rater    L-ROLE
)    O
```

If you're using spaCy, you can specify NER labels with character ranges for training data, which should help with variations in tokenizer input. For details see the [training documentation](https://spacy.io/api/annotation#named-entities).